# Show that f is a continuous function if and only if for every closed set C in Y, $f^{-1}(C)$ is closed in X.

Tags: general-topology, continuity

Suppose X and Y are topological spaces with topology $T^x$  and $T^y$

Let $f: X \to Y$ be a function.

Show that $f$ is a continuous function if and only if for every closed set $C$ in $Y$, $f^{-1}(C)$ is closed in $X$.

I know that $f$ is continuous function if and only if for every open set $O$ in $Y$, $f^{-1}(O)$ is open in $X$.

How do I show for every open set $O$ in $Y$, $f^{-1}(O)$ is open in $X$ if and only if for every closed set $C$ in $Y$, $f^{-1}(C)$ is closed in $X$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**HINT**: If $C$ is closed then $C = Y - O$ for an open set $O$. What is $f^{-1}(Y-O)$? That proves that the inverse of a closed set is closed. Now use the same idea to show the converse statement.

Comment: isn't C = Y- O ?

Comment: Yes, you're right.

Comment: $f^{-1}$(Y-O) is closed in C. How does that prove every open set O in Y, f−1(O) is open in X

Comment: Let $O$ be any open set, then its complement $Y-O$ is closed in $Y$. Hence (by assumption) $f^{-1}(Y-O)$ is closed in $X$. But $f^{-1}(Y-O) =  X - f^{-1}(O)$ and therefore the complement of $f^{-1}(O)$ is closed, which implies ...?

Comment: $f^{-1}(O)$ is open

Comment: Indeed. Therefore we have shown that if the inverse image of every closed set is closed, then the function is continuous.

Comment: is it the same proof for the converse?

Comment: Pretty much. You just need to show that the inverse of a closed set is closed. Now represent a closed set by its complement and do the same argument.

Comment: Why is $f^{−1}(Y−O)=X−f^{−1}(O)$ true?

Answer (score 1):

Hint : $f^{-1}(A^c) = (f^{-1}(A))^c$

Comment: Is this trivial? I don't know why it makes sense.